# What is Object Scope in Oop?

Tags: c++, class, oop, object

Hi I read this definition on internet..

> A destructor is a special member function of a class that is executed
>   whenever an object of it's class goes out of scope or whenever the
>   delete expression is applied to a pointer to the object of that class.

I tried this code..

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class Name{
    public:
        void Fun(){
            cout << "Function" << endl;
        }
        Name(){
            cout << "Constructor" << endl;
        }
        ~Name(){
            cout << "Destructor" << endl;
        }
};
int main(){
    Name obj;
    obj.Fun();
    cout << "End" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

It's calling destructor at the end of program..!! Mean object scope is the end of program? Sorry I'm little confused...

Comment: It's the end of the `main()` function, when the local object `obj` goes out of scope.
In your case, `main()` is also the end of the program, but that's not the normal case.

Comment: You mean obj scope is main body? same as local variable?

Comment: It IS local variable. In this case - yes, the scope is `main()` body.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your case the end of the scope of `obj` is at the end of the `main` function, but it could be any other scope depending on where you define `obj`. Example:

```
int main(){
    // open a new scope here
    {
        // now 'obj' will be in the new scope
        Name obj;
        obj.Fun();
    }
    // the scope ended here, 'obj' destroyed now
    cout << "End" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

You can find [more information here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language), look at "Basic concepts" for "[Scope](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/scope)" and "[Lifetime](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lifetime)".

Comment: Good Example..!! Nice one..!! Thumbs up.. :)

Answer (score 2):

Scope is a region in program that defines life time of objects defined within it. In nearly all cases it is defined by curly brackets. So when you have definition of function it's body defines a scope.

`main` is no special in any way in regard to definition of scope.

Some more cases:

```
int fun(){ // one scope

  for(int i = 0; i < 1337; ++i){ // another scope
    //note that i is defined within `for` scope not outside
  }

  if(true){ // same here
  }

  { // you can even start and end scope at will
     A a;
  } // a will die here

  { // sometimes it is useful for redeclaring a variable, probably not best practice
     A a; // this is legal
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The object obj that you have created is a variable and as any variable it has scope. Scope is defined by curly brackets in which variable was created. In your case the scope of obj that you created is `main` function, because it is placed between curly brackets of that function. And when main function ends, your object is not available anymore (it is available only within that function) and that is why destructor is called.

You can also define scope of your own by just putting your object into curly brackets like that:

```
main(){
    cout<<"scope of the main function"<<endl; 

    {
        cout <<"scope where obj created"<<endl;
        Name obj;
    }
    cout << "obj destroyed"<<endl;

    cout << "End of main" <<endl;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your case its C# program, In the case of object ends it availability after the program ends i.e. after the main is executed the object finds its destructor if it’s not available by programmer then its system generated destructor will be executed an it will destroy all the object and frees up the  memory..

Comment: It might also be when the garbage collector do a sweep. Which can happen at any time during the run