# php Login Verification - How to retrieve and send back a value from a database to method

Tags: php

I am new to PHP and am looking for guidance on how to send data from a database back up to a function for User Login verification purposes, essentially all I need to do is be able to send a user's salt value to the authentication function.

**authentication function code:**

```
$userSalt= $this->saltFinder($user["username"]);
```

This line here sends the username entered into the login form to the function meant to retrieve the user's salt value from the database.

I can retrieve the correct salt value through `sql/sqlite3` statements and some array manipulation (pop/shift/implode) or by selecting the appropriate array index.

**saltFinder function code:**

```
private function saltFinder($user)
{
    $select = "SELECT usersalt FROM users 
    WHERE username = :username";

    $stmt = $this->db->prepare($select);
    $stmt->bindValue(':username', $user, SQLITE3_TEXT);

    $res = $stmt->execute();
    $row = $res->fetchArray();

    $saltValue = $row[0];
}
```

This here will select the correct salt value I require but I am totally stumped on how to send it back up to the appropriate function so that it can continue through its process to complete user login verification.

I have tried using `return()` and if statements but cannot get it working, any guidance on how to solve my issue or direction to information that could help would be appreciated.

**Edit:**

Forgot to mention that both the `authentication` and `saltFinder` functions are within the same class, so as far as I can tell it shouldn't be an object scope issue.

I have attempted a completely different way of retrieving the user's salt value as shown here:

```
private function saltFinder($user)
{
    $arr = array('username'=>$user);
    $sql = "SELECT salt FROM users WHERE username = :username";
    $this->all($sql,$arr);
}
```

which leads to

```
protected function all($sql, $arr = null)
{
    $stmt = $this->db->prepare($sql);
    foreach ($arr as $key => $value) {
        $stmt->bindValue(":$key", $value, SQLITE3_TEXT);
    }
    $results = $stmt->execute();
    $this->outputNestedObject($results);
}
```

and ends at

```
protected function outputNestedObject($result)
{
    $data = array();
    while ($res = $result->fetchArray(1)) {
        array_push($data, $res);
    }
    echo "{\"data\":" . json_encode($data) . "}";
    exit();
}
```

These two protected functions are primarily used for other aspects of my site and I had a thought that maybe I could use them to help with my goal of user authentication and I have ended up with a JSON object displaying the following:

> {"data":[{"salt":"*users salt value*"}]}

This here displays the correct salt value for the user as if it was pulled right from the database but again have no idea on how to send this data back to the authentication function.

Comment: to be able to get function result in this case your function must return the result, also your function (method) is declared as private meaning you can use it only within object scope.

Comment: Use the function where you need by using the function "saltfinder($user);" but return a value within the function. Do not put it in a variable but return it "return $row[0];"  but only return $row[0] when it actually has a value otherwise throw a exception, and tell the user his account it locked because the salt is wrong / not existing.

As george Dryser is saying you might wonder: "What is object scope?" https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30139288/what-is-object-scope-in-oop you need to know this to be able to use object Oriented programming effectively and solve your question roperly.